# How to call this below script?

Tags: php, ssh, vagrant, virtualbox

I have cloned a project from repo in projects directory, where I have got a few files as below. I am confused how it would be called or do i need to call it explicitly ? and this file is not containing any extension LIKE PHP OR SH, and project is in php using Vagrant AND VIRTUAL BOX, I am also not much familiar with VAGRANT.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

installpkg(){
    dpkg-query --status $1 >/dev/null || apt-get install -y $1
}

apt-get update
installpkg php5
installpkg php5-mysql
installpkg redis-server
installpkg mysql-server
installpkg apache2-utils
installpkg apache2-suexec-custom
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That script is a bash script to install PHP, Apache webserver, Mysql and Redis..... it isn't a PHP script itself

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you, so do I need it to run from terminal or it would be auto called from project directory ? please assist

Comment: No, it's a bash script, you need to run it from a terminal (on Linux)

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a [shell provisioning](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html) script that vagrant can execute when booting up the VM. you can add the following to your Vagrantfile so it is executed automatically

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "<path to your file>"
end
```

Comment: @fredrick , Thank you for giving insight